# Why converting to PEM if P12 already works

Tags: iphone, security, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I've just generated an APNS certificate (for push notification) that ends up to a P12 file.

I put this file on my server, associated to its password and the whole works: notifications are well sent to devices.

I read a lot of articles explaining how to convert a P12 file to a PEM file.

Question is: What is the benefit of a PEM file if the P12 already makes the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programs do not support reading the key and certificate from a PKCS #12 (`*.p12`) file.  Others only support PKCS #12, and many support both.

Because your program supports PKCS #12 there is no need (or benefit) to convert to PEM.